# ImageViewer intent shows blank image

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, image-viewer

I save an image under cache at runtime. Then I want to read and show it with system image viewer.

I use below code for under api level 24:

```
File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "sample.png"); 

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);               
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
imgView.setImageURI(uri); // It works 
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent); // It shows an blank image
```

**EDIT**
Upper code works for `/sdcard/test.jpg`. Can I use app cache folder with gallery?